# What was the color puzzle in Tomb Raider?

Tags: plot-explanation, tomb-raider-2018

In [**Tomb Raider**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_Raider_(film)) (2018) there is a scene where the floor falls apart and Lara has to put two color stones in a hole to prevent it. There are several different color stones and at first she put one by one each and it fails to stop the falling floor.

Then she puts two stones together and stops the falling of floor, so how did she figure it out? And what was the puzzle there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They initially assume the correct colour is *black*, due to Himiko being a *death* queen.

> It's a color puzzle.
>
> The death queen turns the day to night...
>
> Black!

But after this (and all subsequent colours) failing to work, Lara realises the reference is *green* from *life*, created by [combining blue and yellow](https://www.physics.wisc.edu/ingersollmuseum/exhibits/optics%26color/subcolormix):

> The death queen turns day to night.
>   She must die, to bring back life.
>   Life.
>
> Come on!
>
> The color of life...
>
> We're running out of floor!
>
> Green!

**However,** since the first attested Japanese accounts of [Himiko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himiko#Japanese_sources) are from the 8th century, and in [Old Japanese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese) the colours 'blue' and 'green' both came under one name *ao* 青 (similar to how 'violet' and 'indigo' are both shades of *purple* in English)<sup>1</sup>, the riddle seems a bit anachronistic.

---

<sup>1. In modern Japanese there is a distinct word for green, *midori* [緑](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%B7%91#Japanese). But this word used to only refer to new buds and shoots, only recently coming to mean the colour via metonymy. Further, *ao* is still used in many terms to refer to 'green' items:</sup>

- <sup>*aoshingou* 青信号あおしんごう ("green traffic light")</sup>
- <sup>*aonegi* 青ネギあおねぎ ("green spring onion.")</sup>

<sup>Further still, *midori* itself can be [ambiguous](https://www.aeon.info/ef/midoripress/japanese/20120306_midori.html):</sup>

> <sup>The word *midori* is also used for representing the dark blue color of the sea as a poetic or literary expression. *Midori* not only means onshore nature but also the sea as a source of life.</sup>
>
> <sup>*Midori* also represents fresh life such as in newborn babies (みどり児, *midorigo*), or the shiny black hair (みどりの黒髪, *midori no kurokami*) of women. These are examples representing original meanings of *midori*.</sup>

---

[The coloured stones](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-SCREEN-USED-TOMB-PUZZLE-PIECE-SET-SC-64-75/183177398262):

[image: The coloured stones] [image: See blue and yellow stone combined]

---

The 'Ordeals of Himiko':

[image]

> #### "Ordeals of Himiko"
>
> Cross the chasm of Souls, witness the futility
>   **Pray to [...] the 8 faces of Himiko**
>   Manifesting the fate of her Enemies
>   Behold her thousand hand-Maidens, blessed
>   by the Ritual [S...]; Descendupon Himiko's
>   final Resting Place
>    Unleashing her Scourge

**Note:** the coloured stones are recovered from the mouths of 8 stone faces carved into the walls of the puzzle room.

---

The quote containing the riddle which solves the puzzle doesn't appear to be in the sample images below, but they may only be a subset of the pages of the actual journal prop:

- [TOMB RAIDER RICHARD CROFT DOMINIC WEST SCREEN USED JOURNAL](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-SCREEN-USED-JOURNAL-/142724317300) (1/2) | 2/2 (?)
- [TOMB RAIDER RICHARD CROFT DOMINIC WEST PRODUCTION USED BACK-UP JOURNAL](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PRODUCTION-USED-BACK-UP-JOURNAL/312107692950) (1/3) | [2/3](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PRODUCTION-USED-BACKUP-JOURNAL/142756629010) | 3/3 (?)
- [TOMB RAIDER RICHARD DOMINIC WEST PRODUCTION USED JOURNAL COVER PIECE & PAGES](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-DOMINIC-WEST-PRODUCTION-USED-JOURNAL-COVER-PIECE-PAGES/183165941597) (1/2) | [2/2](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PRODUCTION-USED-JOURNAL-COVER-PAGES/312110196023)
- [TOMB RAIDER RICHARD CROFT DOMINIC WEST PRODUCTION USED JOURNAL CLIPPING INSERTS](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PRODUCTION-USED-JOURNAL-CLIPPING-INSERTS/142747940924)
- [TOMB RAIDER RICHARD CROFT DOMINIC WEST PROTOTYPE JOURNAL](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PROTOTYPE-JOURNAL/142732197124) (1/2) | [2/2](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/TOMB-RAIDER-RICHARD-CROFT-DOMINIC-WEST-PROTOTYPE-JOURNAL/312099240475)

Answer (score 3):

Because it said Himiko bring life if Himiko died, and Himiko can turn night into day. Based on that relation, Lara think if she want to avoid dead, he need to bring life. The color of life is green. Because there were no green stone, she improvise to make one, by combining yellow and blue to create green.